# Can't zoom in on a mandelbrot set with matplotlib, instead it just cuts off the part I try to zoom

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mandelbrot

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mandelbrot(c):
    z = complex(0, 0)
    for i in range(0, 100):
        z = z*z+c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return(i)
    return 100

M = np.zeros([401, 401])
a = np.linspace(-2, 2, 401)
b = np.linspace(-2, 2, 401)

for x in a:
    for y in b:
        M[round((x+2)*100),  round((y+2)*100)] = mandelbrot(complex(x, y))


plt.imshow(M, cmap='jet', extent=(-2, -2, 2, 2))
plt.show()
```

This works perfectly. The next taxt was to change a and b so that it zooms in on a certain part of the set. I tried changing a and b such that:
a = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 401)
b = np.linspace(-0.5, 0.5, 401)

And also changing extent such that extent=(amin, amax, bmin, bmax).

These are the results:

Original

[image: Original]

Zoom:

[image: Zoom]

AS you can see, it doesn't zoom in on that part and instead it just cuts off a part of it and displays only that. This is where I'm stuck as I can't find a way to actually make it zoom. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the problem is in this line `M[round((x+2)*100),  round((y+2)*100)] = mandelbrot(complex(x, y))`, you are not filling the whole `M`, only its central part

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matplotlib imshow zoom function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665076/matplotlib-imshow-zoom-function). You are using "Extent" rather than setting the xlim and ylim.

Comment: What's a good way to go about that @Enzo? I got that index from my teacher and I'm not sure what to change it to.

Comment: @KristiFrancis see my answer

Comment: @TomMcLean That didn't work onfortunately, I'm honestly not sure what it did but I basically just got an empty image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the values of your arrays `a` and `b` as the indices of the matrix `M`.
What you want is `M[x,y] = mandelbrot(a[x] + i*b[y])`:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mandelbrot(c):
    z = complex(0, 0)
    for i in range(0, 100):
        z = z*z+c
        if abs(z) > 2:
            return(i)
    return 100

numpts = 401
xymin = -.5
xymax = .5

M = np.zeros([numpts, numpts])

a = np.linspace(xymin, xymax, numpts)
b = np.linspace(xymin, xymax, numpts)

for x in range(numpts):
    for y in range(numpts):
        M[x, y] = mandelbrot(complex(a[x], b[y]))


plt.imshow(M, cmap='jet', extent=(xymin, xymax, xymin, xymax))
plt.show()
```

Which gives you the correct result.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't sure of the index part as my teacher supplied it. What was the point before of setting it to (x+2)*100?

Comment: It was just coincidentally set so that it would go from 0 to 400, as (-2+2)*100 is 0 and (2+2)*100 is 400, of course. But as you can see that clearly fails if any of the numbers change. That's why only changing the extent didn't do what you wanted, it only filled in M from indices 150 to 250.